# php dynamic og:image for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, dynamic

Now this is all over stackoverflow but I haven't come across a solution that has worked yet so here goes...

Just trying to get facebook to recognise my og:image pretty simple. Everything outputs with the facebook object debugger except the thumbnail won't show. It does however show the correct url and when the blank thumbnail is clicked it loads the correct image.

Image size is surely not an issue as I have another site that works with much larger images.

Code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $product_name; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.domain.com.au/product-tesst.php?id=<?     echo $id ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image"content="https://www.domain.com.au/inventory_images/thumb_<? echo $id ?>.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Biz Name"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<? echo stripslashes($details) ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the secure image url you are using see this [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/405588419493203)

Short answer use:

```
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.domain.com.au/inventory_images/thumb_<? echo $id ?>.jpg" />
```

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks for your answer. I've added  the suggested meta above but still can't get it to work :( Has to be the secure url though.

Comment: Facebook does cache this data, make sure that's not the problem. The [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) should avoid the cache.

Comment: Yeah just looked into the cache issue. Doesn't look like it is the cache as the debugger is still not showing the thumb. I did clear the cache just to make sure ;)

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is can the image be remotely accessed?

Comment: Do you mean from a standard url e.g. https://www.domain.com.au/image.jpg? If so yes.

Comment: Just had another thought, are you using a valid ssl cert for your domain? I've just tested this and facebook won't generate a thumbnail if your site doesn't have a valid ssl cert.

Comment: yeah valid ssl cert. Thanks for your help with this PieSub it's much appreciated. I can always just upload an image on fb, just trying to make it easier for my client.